# Cannot GET / when using yo angular scaffolding

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm trying to get the Yeoman 1.0 beta's angular scaffolding working by following these workflow steps:

```
npm install generator-angular generator-testacular  # install generators
yo angular                     # scaffold out a AngularJS project
npm install && bower install   # install default dependencies
grunt server                   # preview your app
```

When I run:

```
grunt server
```

I get a page with:

> Cannot GET /

and when run:

```
grunt
```

I get a dist folder with only scripts folder in it.
The basic scaffolding should serve a basic page out of the box right?

Any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a recent bug on Github. BTFord just addressed it and this also fixed the problem for me.

Adjust line 18 in Gruntfile.js to read:

yeomanConfig.app = require('./component.json').appPath **|| 'app'**;

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/commit/3a5a9dfea964b41d053d7e5fcb18906ace89aeda

Answer (score 0):

I received this error after I accidentally moving my `app` folder.

Simply put it back in my `ProjectName` folder and it fixed it.

Hope it helps if some else comes across this issue.